# How can I calculate the cosine of latitude as weights for gridded precipitation values?

Tags: r

I am working with a raster brick that contains gridded precipitation data (8192 grid cells for 140 layers). However, because the areas near the poles are larger relative to those areas near the equator, it becomes necessary to apply weights by using the cosine of latitude. However, I am receiving strange values and was not sure if I was doing this correctly. I would like to do apply these weights to each of the grid cells for each of the 140 layers. Here is what I have done so far:

```
Model2 <- brick("MaxPrecCCCMACanESM21pctCO2.nc", var="onedaymax")
new <- rasterToPoints(Model2)
weight<- cos(new[,"y"]*(pi/180))
newprec <- apply(new[,3:ncol(new)], 2, function(x) x * weight)
```

Here are the derived precipitation values for the first few grid cells:

```
> newprec
              X1           X2           X3           X4           X5           X6           X7           
X8
[1,]   0.27567528   0.24205794   0.27703410   0.25225538   0.43462864   0.26681639   0.52068429   
0.30341760
[2,]   0.27127565   0.23553404   0.31334782   0.22269904   0.46649158   0.27605592   0.57219751   
0.29737593
[3,]   0.25791578   0.22808846   0.35357911   0.23320888   0.50118092   0.28115661   0.40429370   
0.31467036
[4,]   0.24726204   0.23485372   0.38576613   0.25100560   0.53510838   0.28291017   0.46415740   
0.31253770
[5,]   0.26043152   0.26307936   0.41757709   0.29961563   0.56215398   0.28584261   0.44126914   
0.31707329
[6,]   0.27163764   0.28184050   0.45071078   0.31253864   0.58024153   0.28563418   0.33270020   
0.35154895
[7,]   0.29662650   0.28822337   0.52179242   0.33481873   0.57810949   0.28326347   0.31865999   
 0.30893378
    X9          X10          X11          X12          X13          X14          X15          X16
[1,]   0.29551221   0.38643225   0.31908628   0.20627933   0.39268046   0.45240661   0.3316521 
0.37557260
[2,]   0.29968592   0.36144125   0.34942253   0.22403266   0.38389816   0.47353695   0.35494386   
0.41303691
[3,]   0.30398685   0.37758057   0.37552215   0.24564733   0.35611095   0.47643618   0.33604546   
0.42336511
[4,]   0.32420756   0.37371012   0.39471952   0.26249758   0.32805687   0.45818970   0.42707286   
0.44590961
[5,]   0.33468238   0.36156798   0.38230730   0.28380474   0.35848330   0.42909070   0.42969315   
0.48266150
[6,]   0.33470307   0.37452035   0.40623552   0.30364748   0.34336817   0.41937878   0.42803487   
0.51959504
[7,]   0.32599735   0.35396442   0.40487938   0.31876450   0.33019248   0.38832444   0.42091250   
0.56627930
```

These values seem quite low, though, so I am not sure if I am doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple self-contained reproducible example.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(res=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
```

To get the area of each grid cell

```
a <- area(r)
plot(a)
```

Or following your logic, using the cosine

```
lat <- init(r, "y") * (pi/180)
clat <- cos(lat)
plot(clat)
```

To apply these weights, you can do

```
rw <- r * clat
```

Perhaps you then want to do something like this

```
s <- stack(rw, r)
```

And use `zonal` to compute zonal sums for the weighted values and the weights, and divide one by the other to get the weighted mean.